# Taylor Series of a Function with Periodic Derivatives

Tags: code-golf, string, math, sequence, calculus

Taylor series are a very useful tool in calculating values of analytic functions that cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions, using only information about that function at a single point.

In this challenge, you won't be actually doing any math with them, but merely making string representations of taylor series of functions with periodic derivatives.

## Specs

You will takes a input three things:

1. A cycle of the derivatives of the function, including the original function as a list of strings, e.g. `["sin(x)", "cos(x)", "-sin(x)", "-cos(x)"]`.
2. A number `a`, the point around which to center the approximation.
3. A positive integer `n`, the number of terms of the series to output.

The general form for the nth term of a taylor series is:

```
f^(n)(a)/n!*(x-a)^n
```

where `f^(n)` is the nth derivative of `f`. Here is the taylor series of `f` in a better formatted image from wikipedia:

[image].

The above example with `sin(x)`, and `a` of 1, and `n` of 6, would have an output of:

```
sin(1) + cos(1)*(x-1) - sin(1)/2*(x-1)^2 - cos(1)/6*(x-1)^3 + sin(1)/24*(x-1)^4 + cos(1)/120*(x-1)^5
```

You can do the whitespace want. However, you have to replace `+ -` and `- -` with `-` and `+` respectively. Also, if the series is a maclaurin series, and `a` is `0`, you cannot have `(x-0)`. `(x)` and just `x` is fine, but not `(x-0)`. Niether can you have `^0` nor `^1` nor `/1` . Additionally, you must expand out the factorials in the denominators. Multiplication by juxtaposition is not allowed.

## Test cases

```
["e^x"], 0, 4  ->  e^0 + e^0*x + e^0*x^2/2 + e^0*x^3/6
["sin(x)", "cos(x)", "-sin(x)", "-cos(x)"], 1, 6 -> sin(1) + cos(1)*(x-1) - sin(1)/2*(x-1)^2 - cos(1)/6*(x-1)^3 + sin(1)/24*(x-1)^4 + cos(1)/120*(x-1)^5
["e^(i*x)", "i * e^(i*x)", "-e^(i*x)", "-i*e^(i*x)"], 0, 7 -> e^(i*0) + i*e^(i*0)*x - e^(i*0)*x^2/2 - i*e^(i*0)*x^3/6 + e^(i*0)*x^4/24 + i*e^(i*0)*x^5/120 - e^(i*0)*x^6/720
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in **bytes** wins!

Comment: Are built ins allowed?

Comment: @Mego sure, if you can find one that doesn't evaluate the function and only does string manipulation.

Comment: What about something like [this](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLs81JzE1KSVRI0cnXKdGpsC1LLNJQr1DXtEotS8zRSIk2iNXUK0mszMkv0qgAKdHk5eLlKijKzCtRSNOIVirOzNOo0FTSUVBKzi-GsnQRgrpQ0VgdBUMdBTNNAHaCH8o=&lang=sage)?

Comment: Additionally, can `**` be used in place of `^`?

Comment: May we assume that the derivatives only start with nothing or a single minus sign if they're negative?

Comment: Can the function's name include the letter `x` or will it only be the variable?

Comment: @Mego sure, sage is fine, and so is using **

Comment: @orlp you can assume that all occurrences of x refer to the variable.

Comment: @Maltysen That wasn't my question. Can we assume that the derivatives won't contain stuff like this: `["--sin(x)", "--cos(x)", "sin(x)*-1", "cos(x)*-1"]`? Always either no sign or a single unary minus.

Comment: @orlp sorry, was on mobile, pinged wrong person. yeah assuming that is fine.

Comment: @Neil sorry, was on mobile pinged wrong person, you can assume that all occurrences of x refer to the variable

Comment: Your first example with `e^x` has 4 terms, not the requested 3.

Comment: @orlp whoops, fixing.

Comment: @Maltysen Is it okay if, for the first test case, `e^0/2*x^2` is output for the third value in the series instead of `e^0*x^2/2`?

Comment: @R.Kap sure, that's fine

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 183 bytes

```
(c,a,n)=>[...Array(n)].map((_,i)=>(s=c[i%c.length].replace(/x/g,a),i?s=s.replace(/^-?/,c=>c?` - `:` + `)+(a>0?`*(x-${a})`:a<0?`*(x+${-a})`:`*x`):s,i>1?s+`^${i}/${f*=i}`:s),f=1).join``
```

Lots of tedious string manipulation. Explanation:

```
(c,a,n)=>                               Parameters
 [...Array(n)].map((_,i)=>(             Loop i from 0 to n-1
  s=c[i%c.length]                       Get the right element from the cycle
   .replace(/x/g,a),                    Substitute a in for x
  i?                                    If i > 0
   s=s.replace(/^-?/,c=>c?` - `:` + `)  Turn the sign into an operator
    +(a>0?`*(x-${a})`                   If a > 0 then * (x - a)
     :a<0?`*(x+${-a})`                  If a < 0 then * (x + -a)
     :`*x`)                             If a == 0 then * x
   :s,                                  No change if i < 1
  i>1?                                  If i > 1
   s+`^${i}/${f*=i}`                    Append ^ i / i!
   :s),                                 No change if i < 2
  f=1                                   0! == 1
 ).join``                               Join all the results together
```

170 bytes if you remove all the whitespace:

```
(c,a,n)=>[...Array(n)].map((_,i)=>(s=c[i%c.length].replace(/x/g,a),i?s=(s[0]=='-'?'':'+')+s+(a>0?`*(x-${a})`:a<0?`*(x+${-a})`:`*x`):s,i>1?s+`^${i}/${f*=i}`:s),f=1).join``
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 181 bytes

```
D,a,N=input()
D=["+"*(d[0]!="-")+d.replace("x",`a`)for d in D]
x=a and"*(x-%s)"%a or"*x"
r=D[0][1:]+(D[1]+x)*(N>1)
n=f=2
while n<N:r+=D[n%len(D)]+"/"+`f`+x+"^"+`n`;n+=1;f*=n
print r
```

Comment: Maybe a short explanation on how this works?

Comment: @R.Kap There's nothing to explain, really. It's just a bunch of string concatenation. Each line reasonably speaks for itself.

Comment: I mean, what's going on in `x`? What are the `and` and `or` doing there?

Comment: @R.Kap `x` is simply `"*(x-a)"` or just `"*x"` if `a` is 0.

Comment: I would presume that you would have to use ternary `if` statements for that, but this I did not know was even possible.

Comment: @R.Kap Nope, 1 newline = 1 semicolon.

Comment: `r` returns a `IndexError` on `["e^x"],0,4`. I did run this on Python 3, although, based on what `r` is supposed to be, it should work the same on both Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3.5, <strike>308</strike> 299 bytes:

```
def g(f,a,n,L=len,S=str):import math,re;A=S(a);print('+'.join(t.replace('x',A)+re.sub('(\W\(x-\d+\)\^0|/1|\*1|\^1|\*0)(?!\d+)','',g)for t,g in zip(f*(n//L(f))+f[:n%L(f)],['*'+A+'/'+S(math.factorial(n))+'*'+'(x-'+A+')^'+S(n)for n in range(n)])).replace('+-','-').replace('--','+').replace('x-0','x'))
```

<strike>This *always* outputs in the order according to the equation `f^(n)(a)/n!*(x-a)^n`. For instance, if the expected output for one of the terms is `e^0*x^2/2`, it instead outputs `e^0/2*x^2`. However, they are both basically the same answer, so I hope this is okay.</strike> [Confirmed by OP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/78424/taylor-series-of-a-function-with-periodic-derivatives/78682#comment192711_78424) that this is okay. This works perfectly as I have had no issues with it. I will shorten this over time wherever I can.

**Note:** In the output, all `(x-0)` are replaced with `(x)`.

[Try it online! (Ideone)](http://ideone.com/TuPBut) (Accepts input on 3 lines, where the first line is the input list, `f`, the second line is `a`, and the third line is `n`)

## Explanation

For the purposes of this explanation, assume the function is executed with the values `"e^(i*x)", "i*e^(i*x)", "-e^(i*x)", "-i*e^(i*x)"],0,7`. That being said, basically, what's going on in the main part, step-by-step, is:

1. `'+'.join(t.replace('x',A)+re.sub('(\W\(x-\d+\)\^0|/1|\*1|\^1|\*0)(?!\d+)','',g)for t,g in zip(f*(n//L(f))+f[:n%L(f)],['*'+A+'/'+S(math.factorial(n))+'*'+'(x-'+A+')^'+S(n)for n in range(n)]))`

   A list is created from each item pair in a zip object containing the input list, `f`, with `n` number of items, and another list which contains each term in the sequence *except* the items in `f`. In this second list, `*+a` is added, followed by a `/`+ `n!` for each value, `n`, in the range `n`, and finally, a lone `*` followed by `(x-a)^n`. After all this is done, for each item pair in this zip object, `t` corresponding to each object in `f` and `g` corresponding to each value in the second list, each `'x'` in `t` is replaced with `a`, and every `g` goes through a regular expression substitution, namely `(\W\(x-\d+\)\^0|/1|\*1|\^1|\*0)(?!\d+)`, in which every `(x-a)^0`, `/1`,`*1`,`^1`, and `*0` is matched and replaced with `''` as long as each of those are *not* followed by any more integers. After all this substitution is done, each `t` and `g` are concatenated together, and each term created using this method is joined with `+`s and returned. For this particular case in which `"e^(i*x)", "i*e^(i*x)", "-e^(i*x)", "-i*e^(i*x)"],0,7` is the input, this part would return:

   ```
   e^(i*0)+i*e^(i*0)*(x-0)+-e^(i*0)/2*(x-0)^2+-i*e^(i*0)/6*(x-0)^3+e^(i*0)/24*(x-0)^4+i*e^(i*0)/120*(x-0)^5+-e^(i*0)/720*(x-0)^6
   ```

   As you can see, those `+-`s, `--`s, and `(x-0)`s exist. However, these will all be replaced with `-`,`+`,and `(x)` respectively in the next part.
2. `'+'.join(t.replace('x',A)+re.sub('(\W\(x-\d+\)\^0|/1|\*1|\^1|\*0)(?!\d+)','',g)for t,g in zip(f*(n//L(f))+f[:n%L(f)],['*'+A+'/'+S(math.factorial(n))+'*'+'(x-'+A+')^'+S(n)for n in range(n)])).replace('+-','-').replace('--','+').replace('x-0','x')`

   Here is where those substrings such as `+-`,`++`,and `(x-0)` in the now joined string are replaced with their correct substitutes using Python's built-in sub-string replacement function. After all the replacing has been done, this finally returns the finished product, which in this case would be:

   ```
   e^(i*0)+i*e^(i*0)*(x)-e^(i*0)/2*(x)^2-i*e^(i*0)/6*(x)^3+e^(i*0)/24*(x)^4+i*e^(i*0)/120*(x)^5-e^(i*0)/720*(x)^6
   ```